# How to efficiently iterate over a list of tuples and group similar tuples?

Tags: python-3.x

I have created the below script to identify unique users by comparing values for device id and profile id. Each tuple below represents a unique combination of (device_id, profile_id) for a user.

Each unique user will be identified by a randomly generated uuid str(uuid.uuid4()).

Each uuid should include all combinations of related (device_id, profile_id). Related means sharing a device_id or a profile_id.

```py
from operator import itemgetter
import uuid

device_id_profile_id = [
    (None, '35570420'),
    ('1D3648C45C8B', '35281761'),
    ('BCCEC3F05553', None),
    ('1D3648C45C8B', '35570420'),
    ('1D3648C45C8B', None),
    ('D5BB8D3C741E', '35281761'),
    ('DFDF67821F4B', '35281761'),
    ('BCCEC3F05553', '34926860'),
    ('BCCEC3F04487', '34926860'),
    ('BCCEC3F04487', None),
    ('BCCEC3F04487', '44945781'),
    ('7229143E0B4C', '35570420')
]

final_output = {}
uuid_by_device_id = {}
uuid_by_profile_id = {}

device_id_profile_id_copy = device_id_profile_id.copy()

processed_ids = set()

for i, e in enumerate(device_id_profile_id):

    for e_copy in device_id_profile_id_copy:

        if (e[0] is not None and e[0] == e_copy[0]) or (e[1] is not None and e[1] == e_copy[1]):    
            if e_copy not in processed_ids:
                processed_ids.add(e_copy)
                if uuid_by_device_id.get(e_copy[0]) is None and uuid_by_profile_id.get(e_copy[1]) is None:
                    uuid_s = str(uuid.uuid4())
                else:
                    uuid_s = uuid_by_device_id.get(e_copy[0], uuid_by_profile_id.get(e_copy[1]))

                if e_copy[0] is not None:
                    uuid_by_device_id[e_copy[0]] = uuid_s
                if e_copy[1] is not None:
                    uuid_by_profile_id[e_copy[1]] = uuid_s

                v = final_output.get(uuid_s, []) 
                v.append(e_copy)
                final_output[uuid_s] = v

print(final_output)
```

The code works as expected and you can see the output below.
The issue is that the execution time is too slow for the number of inputs I want to process. I was thinking to use a parallel computation framework but first I would like to know if the above code could be improved in terms of efficiency.

```
{
    '3fa59a8f-69e5-4fcf-80c3-b996c8606405': [
        (None, '35570420'), 
        ('1D3648C45C8B', '35570420'), 
        ('7229143E0B4C', '35570420'), 
        ('1D3648C45C8B', '35281761'), 
        ('1D3648C45C8B', None), 
        ('D5BB8D3C741E', '35281761'), 
        ('DFDF67821F4B', '35281761')],
    'c3fb8131-deb9-4921-bf60-b9b397d5a481': [
        ('BCCEC3F05553', None), 
        ('BCCEC3F05553', '34926860'), 
        ('BCCEC3F04487', '34926860'), 
        ('BCCEC3F04487', None), 
        ('BCCEC3F04487', '44945781')]
}
```

Comment: How do you want to deal with transitivity? Your definition has tuples "related" if they share a profile id or device id, but your example output has, e.g. `(None, '35570420')` related to `('1D3648C45C8B', '35281761')` just because they're linked by a chain of related tuples. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how you obtained the uuids but this works:

```
import numpy as np

def relation(data,dat=None,**kwargs):
    if dat is None : 
        dat = set(data) 
        data = np.array(data)
    final = kwargs.get('f',[])
    x = kwargs.get('x',np.array(list(dat)[0]).reshape(-1))
    y = set(x.flatten().tolist())
    x = x[x!=None]
    k = data[np.in1d(data[:,1],x)|np.in1d(data[:,0],x)]
    if set(k.flatten())==y:
        final.append(set(zip(*zip(*k))))
        if dat - final[-1]: return relation(data, dat-final[-1], f=final)
    else: return relation(data,dat,x=k,f=final) 
    return dict(enumerate(final))

relation(device_id_profile_id)
Out: 
{0: [(None, '35570420'),
  ('1D3648C45C8B', '35281761'),
  ('1D3648C45C8B', '35570420'),
  ('1D3648C45C8B', None),
  ('D5BB8D3C741E', '35281761'),
  ('DFDF67821F4B', '35281761'),
  ('7229143E0B4C', '35570420')],
 1: [('BCCEC3F05553', None),
  ('BCCEC3F05553', '34926860'),
  ('BCCEC3F04487', '34926860'),
  ('BCCEC3F04487', None),
  ('BCCEC3F04487', '44945781')]}
```

Comment: Thanks @onyambu, this looks great. I am currently tested your code. I obtained the uuids with `str(uuid.uuid4())`. Could you point out where should I replace in your code? Thanks!

Comment: when running your code on 1000000 inputs, I get the following error:
`Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.`.

This is the code I used to generate the input:

```
device_id_profile_id = []

for i in range(0, 10**6):
    device_id_profile_id.append((str(uuid.uuid4()), str(random.randint(2000000, 4000000))))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at this problem is that you have a set of nodes (all of your tuples), a set of edge relationships (two nodes are related if and only if they have a user id or profile id in common), and you want to find all the *connected components* of the graph defined by those nodes and edges.

You can use your favorite graph library (or implement the component search yourself), but I rather like `networkx` and will use it for demonstration purposes.

```
# Necessary Imports
from networkx import Graph, connected
from uuid import uuid4
from itertools import product
```

There are really two parts to this problem. The first is that your data isn't structured in a way that's amenable to most graph algorithms, and any solution is going to need an efficient way to figure out which nodes are neighbors. Your solution had a *quadratic* algorithm that compared each node to every other node. Since you have keys identifying each node you can get away with something a lot more efficient. I used dictionaries to keep track of the last node seen with a given user/device, but lots of solutions exist.

Note that this scales to any tuple size by varying the two `range(2)` statements. Also note that it doesn't handle an all-`None` tuple -- which would always be in its own component with the metric you've described. If that's actually valid data in your scenario you'll need to identify it somehow, e.g. by checking if the input length is equal to the sum of the component sizes.

```
g = Graph()
caches = [{} for i in range(2)]
for i, node in product(range(2), device_id_profile_id):
    key, cache = node[i], caches[i]
    if key is None:
        # If you ever had the tuple (None, None) it would never be reached
        continue
    last = cache.get(key, None)
    if last is not None:
        g.add_edge(node, last)
    else:
        g.add_node(node)
    cache[key] = node
```

Strictly speaking this code doesn't add all the edges in the graph. As an example, if you had a graph with edges `(a,b)`, `(b,c)`, and `(c,a)` then this algorithm would probably only add `(a,b)` and `(b,c)`. That's purely out of laziness on my part and because it doesn't matter for a connected component search. There is still *some* path from `a` to `c` in that scenario, so they'll still wind up together.

Once you have a graph built you just need to pull the connected components out, and this is where networkx really shines and minimizes the amount of work you need to do for an efficient solution. Most of what we're doing here is just formatting the components that networkx gives us to look the same as in your example code.

```
final_output = {str(uuid4()):list(component)
    for component in connected.connected_components(g)}
```